# Create a List with spaces without and not using .split()

Tags: python-3.x, list, arraylist, whitespace

I have to write an application that asks the user to enter a list of numbers separated by a space and then prints the sum of the numbers. The user can enter any number of numbers. I am not allowed to use the split function in python. I was wondering how I can do it that. Any help would be appreciated it as I'm kind of stuck on where to start.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution is to use regular expressions:

```
# import regular expression library
import re

# let user enter numbers and store user data into 'data' variable 
data = input("Enter numbers separated by space: ")

"""
regular expression pattern '\d+' means the following: 
'\d' - any number character, 
'+' - one or more occurence of the character
're.findall' will find all occurrences of regular expression pattern
and store to list like '['1', '258', '475', '2', '6']'
please note that list items stored as str type
"""
numbers = re.findall(r'\d+', data)

"""
list comprehension '[int(_) for _ in numbers]' converts 
list items to int type
'sum()' - summarizes list items
"""
summary = sum([int(_) for _ in numbers])

print(f'Sum: {summary}')
```

[image]

Another solution is following:

```
string = input("Enter numbers separated by space: ")
splits = []
pos = -1
last_pos = -1

while ' ' in string[pos + 1:]:
    pos = string.index(' ', pos + 1)
    splits.append(string[last_pos + 1:pos])
    last_pos = pos

splits.append(string[last_pos + 1:])

summary = sum([int(_) for _ in filter(None, splits)])
print(f'Sum: {summary}')
```

From my point of view, the first option is more concise and better protected from user errors.

Comment: Thanks for the answer could you possibly explain how this works, I am a beginner and just want more clarity in how this works. Thanks you for the help.

Comment: @Sielko, Hello! I've added comments to the code and another possible solution.

Comment: thank you I appreciate the comments

Comment: @GreyMurav This is a study/homework question. `split` is forbidden so that they can learn how to iterate through character and detect spaces manually, so `regex` is not really the best solution. Otherwise we could simply do `sum(map(int, user_input.split(" ")))`.

Comment: @Guimoute, Clearly, there is no reason not to use split except for programming exercises. Split by space is the default value for split, so the parameter can be omitted like `sum(map(int, user_input.split()))`

Comment: Yes it's any form of whitespace, just like `strip`. For example `"123\t\n456".split() == ["123", "456"]`.